# How to get server-group status in jboss-cli

Tags: jboss

How can I get server-group status (started|stopped) via `jboss-cli.sh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it is not correct to talk about server-group status. server-group may consist of several server-configs and they in turn may have different statuses.
To find out the server-config status, the following command may be used:

```
/opt/jboss7/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command='ls /host=nodeName/server-config=serverName' | grep 'status='
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above accepted answer, but in Wildfly 23 (as of July 2023), I find this gives a more concise and more manageable response:

```
/host=ISERVER/server-config=demo:read-attribute(name=status)
```

(in the accepted answer grep doesn't filter the status onto one line, at least in latest versions of Wildfly)